# Gravar valor de uma constante através de um form

Tags: php

Tenho um arquivo config.php com vários defines através de um form.

Se existir uma define assim:

```
define("NAME","Rodrigo");
```

e outro assim:

```
define("MEU_NOME","Rodrigo");
```

e no meu HTML eu tiver apenas UM input:

```
<?php include(config.php) ?>
<input type="text" id="NAME" value="<?=NAME?>" name="MSSQL_Pass">
```

Se o input enviar o nome "Danilo", ele grava esse nome nos dois defines, mesmo eu não tendo outro input com o ID e o NAME igual ao define que eu quero gravar.

Essa é minha função:

```
function write(){
$file = fopen("config.php","rb");
    $MainContents = "";
    while(!feof($file)) $MainContents .= fgets($file);

    fseek($file, 0);

    while(!feof($file))
    {
        $Main = fscanf($file,'%[^;]');
        if(strpos($Main[0],"//") === false && strpos($Main[0],"?") === false && isset($Main[0]))
        {
            $data = explode("\",",$Main[0]);
            $const = str_replace("define(\"", "", $data[0]);
            $value = str_replace(")", "", $data[1]);

            $myVar = trim($const);

            if(!empty($_POST[$myVar]))
            {
                $new = ($_POST[$myVar] == "true" || $_POST[$myVar] == "false") ? $_POST[$myVar] : "\"" . $_POST[$myVar] . "\"";
                $MainContents = str_replace($value, " " . $new ,$MainContents);
            }
        }
    }

    fclose($file);

    $file = fopen("config.php","wb");
    fwrite($file, $MainContents);
    fclose($file);

    echo " <div class=\"success-box\">Configura&ccedil;&otilde;es salvas com sucesso!</div>";

}
```

Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: `ele grava esse nome nos dois defines` - Como assim Gravar em Constantes??? Modifique essa pergunta, amigo.

Comment: Realmente não está deixando muito claro, mas ele não está alterando a constante em si e sim fisicamente o arquivo que gera a constante.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro ponto:

- No seu form o name do campo não pode ser `MSSQL_Pass` se você quer receber o `value` `name`;

Segundo ponto:

- Você precisa usar `hardcode` se quiser usar esta regra

  ```
  function write(){
  $file = fopen("config.php","rb");
  $MainContents = "";
  while(!feof($file)) $MainContents .= fgets($file);
      fseek($file, 0);

  while(!feof($file))
  {

      $Main = fscanf($file,'%[^;]');
      if(strpos($Main[0],"//") === false && strpos($Main[0],"?") === false && isset($Main[0]))
      {
          $data = explode("\",",$Main[0]);
          $const = str_replace("define(\"", "", $data[0]);
          $value = str_replace(")", "", $data[1]);

          $myVar = trim($const);

          $myVar = ($myVar == "MEU_NOME" && !isset($_POST[$myVar]) ? "NAME" : $myVar;

          if(!empty($_POST[$myVar]))
          {
              $new = ($_POST[$myVar] == "true" || $_POST[$myVar] == "false") ? $_POST[$myVar] : "\"" . $_POST[$myVar] . "\"";
              $MainContents = str_replace($value, " " . $new ,$MainContents);
          }
      }
  }
  fclose($file);
  $file = fopen("config.php","wb");
  fwrite($file, $MainContents);
  fclose($file);

  echo " <div class=\"success-box\">Configura&ccedil;&otilde;es salvas com sucesso!</div>";
  }
  ```

Comment: eu esqueci de alterar o name, eu só postei um exemplo mas a função original esta certinho

Comment: Entendi, o ideal é você postar  o código original, de qualquer forma a resposta ajudou ou o problema ainda persiste?